# jQuery .load() not working on my image

Tags: jquery

I have some code I am trying to run once my image has finished loading. I use this following jQuery code:

```
$("#myimageid").load(function() {
    alert('Image Loaded');
});
```

However the popup never show up. I can't get the .load() function to work ! Anyone had issues with this?

Comment: Where exactly have you placed that code?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you're running this **after** the image already has a set source, you need to do an additional check for caches images (who fired the event, just before you added an event handler listening for it). You can do that like this:

```
$("#myimageid").on('load', function() {
  alert('Image Loaded'); 
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Update for later versions of query, use:

```
if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
```

Using `(this).load();` will produce a `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` error

Comment: That worked ! Thanks mate

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#googleimage").load(function() {
                    alert('Image Loaded');
                }).each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).load(); });
            });

Comment: nice, why was this so hard to find!

Comment: Was just going to downvote for not working solution when I realized I was missing a dot when selecting my class. Duh! Thanks & upvoted!

Comment: This solved my iPad images loading issue. Guess there is something strange when images are cached on iPad

Comment: Among several fixes, this is the one that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work if the image doesn't exist on the server.
you should better try

function urlExists(testUrl) {
 var http = jQuery.ajax({
    type:"HEAD",
    url: testUrl,
    async: false
  })
  return http.status;
      // this will return 200 on success, and 0 or negative value on error
}
then use

if(urlExists('urlToImgOrAnything') == 200) {
    // success
}
else {
    // error
}
source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327655/jquery-check-if-image-exists

Comment: @GeorgeSEDRA that's solving a *completely* different problem and isn't at all appropriate for most cases.  This question is "I want to do something when my image loads", not "how do I check if the images even exist?"  Including images that don't exist in your page is a whole separate question, problem, and discussion.  The code in the answer works correctly as-is, it triggers when an image finishes loading *if and when* it finishes loading.

Comment: Worth noting `.complete` is not defined by jQuery but on the DOM element itself. Therefore `$(selector).complete == undefined` so you might want unwrap it `$(selector)[0].complete`. The answer implies this as $.each assigns raw DOM elems as `this` but I got confused for a wild moment :)

Comment: @NickCraver, but this ain't working if i add an image dynamically. How to get the event in that case? :-/

Comment: @SahilMittal you just need to attach the event before before setting the `src` attribute which causes the load to happen.

Comment: +1, right. How can i ask such thing ! Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @yoshi is correct. I believe `$(selector).prop("complete")` should also work.

Comment: In jquery 3 `if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');`

Comment: Confirming @hlcs comment that one has to use `$(this).trigger('load');` and not `$(this).load();` which will give an error in jQuery 3.1.0 and probably other versions

Comment: But the `alert('Image Loaded'); ` sometimes triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you clear your browser's cache and try the script again?  From the jQuery `load()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> It is possible that the load event
>   will not be triggered if the image is
>   loaded from the browser cache. To
>   account for this possibility, we can
>   use a special load event that fires
>   immediately if the image is ready.
>   event.special.load is currently
>   available as a plugin
>
> In general, it is not necessary to
>   wait for all images to be fully
>   loaded. If code can be executed
>   earlier, it is usually best to place
>   it in a handler sent to the .ready()
>   method.

So it sounds like your cached image isn't triggering the load event, so you may want to try the plug-in that's mentioned.  You can find the JS file to download [here](http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js).

Hope this helps!