# Jquery works in every browser other than IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For IE this code worked and I did the IE comment that only IE can read..

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{

    //--my code
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() 
        {
            $('#mainImage').hide();
            $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', "url('ajax-loader.gif')");
            var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() 
            {
                $('#mainImage').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
                $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
                $('#mainImage').fadeIn();
            });
            return false; 
        });
    });
};


</script> <![endif]-->
```

For Every other browser this code worked...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
        $('#mainImage').hide();
        $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', "url('ajax-loader.gif')");
        var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function() {
            $('#mainImage').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
            $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
            $('#mainImage').fadeIn();
        });
        return false; 
    });
});


</script>
```

I got the working code, even though they each do something different, they do what I need them to do. The only thing is IE doesn't want to read the code to do what I need... What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: E is famous for caching. Delete your cached files and see what happens.

Comment: I did, nothing, I deleted all history too, still nothing. Is there a special way I need to do it with out admin privs?

Answer (score 4):

You've got too many closing braces in your IE6 version, see here:

```
});
}; <- delete me
```

Remove the `};` and you should be good :)

Edit: You've also got a rogue `{` at the start too, get rid of that as well, it's here:

```
{ <- delete that!

//--my code
$(document).ready(function() 
{
```

Comment: Ah that's because you have a random `{` above the function! Just spotted that, get rid of that too.

Answer (score 1):

Are the opening and closing braces on the outside of your document.ready() part of you code?

Remove the first

```
{
```

and also the last

```
};
```

You don't need to wrap everything in braces.

Answer (score 0):

Swap these two around:

```
$('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load(function()
```

should be

```
$('<img />').load(function(){...}).attr('src',this.href)...
```

so that it will work in IE6-IE8 once the image is cached.

Reference to this answer: [Check if dynamically loaded images are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609422/check-if-dynamically-loaded-images-are-complete/10609458#10609458)

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Rocket see the two fiddles in my answer there, one will work in IE8 with every load and the other will only work the first load.

Comment: I switch it talking about this right? ` ('background-image', "url('ajax-loader.gif')");
        var i = `var i = $('<img />').attr('src',this.href).load`
   (function() 
  {`

Comment: I was testing in Chrome, and it didn't matter, guess it would in IE.

Comment: Yes Jakob, however it won't actually fix the issue you are having, matty's answer is what will make your code run. This will just fix a weird bug that you may have run into later if not fixed.

Comment: I used Matty's answer and now adding in yours but when I insert I have an error.