# javascript loaded img still has 0 height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This problem is annoying me because it works with one set of images and not with another.

I have a this object:

```
function PreLoader(toLoad, parent, images) {
  var errored = 0;
  var loaded  = 0;
  var toLoad  = toLoad;

  function allLoaded() {
    // reset the counters so it can be used again
    loaded  = 0;
    errored = 0;

    // determine which img is the tallest
    var l = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      l = (l > images[i].height()) ? l : images[i].height();
    }

    // set the height of the container to the tallest
    // unless it's already bigger
    // height() is from jQuery
    if (parent.obj.height() < l)
      parent.obj.css("height", l);
  }

  this.load  = function() {
    ++loaded;
    if (loaded + errored == toLoad)
      allLoaded();
  };

  this.error = function() {
    ++errored;
    if (loaded + errored == toLoad)
      allLoaded();
  };
}
```

I have been using it in a similar way to this:

```
var parent = {obj: $("#some-img-container")};
var slabLoader = new PreLoader(2, parent, [external.slab, internal.slab]);
external.slab.src = "2.png";
external.slab.onload  = slabLoader.load;
external.slab.onerror = slabLoader.error;
internal.slab.src = "1.png";
internal.slab.onload  = slabLoader.load;
internal.slab.onerror = slabLoader.error;
```

The problem is, sometimes it doesn't work. I have multiple sets of images that are absolute positioned because they are layered on top of each other, but they can be different heights. Obviously I can't hard code the heights because I don't know what they are before the page loads... and because absolute positioned elements don't affect their parents size I can't rely on things like `height: 100%`.

`var l` in the `allLoaded()` function sometimes returns 0 even though the images should be loaded by the time that is called.

Am I correct in this statement or am I doing something wrong and it only works sometimes because of luck?

The html looks like this:

```
<div class='wrapper-hover'>
  <div class='wrapper-content'>
    <a herf='#' id='some-img-container' class='viewport'>
      <!-- this is where the image goes, added by the script -->
    </a>
    <div class='wrapper-caption'>
      <label class='wrapper-caption-content'>Some Image</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if the question is a bit difficult to understand.

***UPDATE:***

If I use `.naturalHeight` instead of jQuery `.height()`I get the height of the actual image on disk and not the height that it would take up after it has been scaled by css (I'm using `width: 100%` and leaving the height undefined). However it still does nothing for the images that returned 0 before.

I can confirm that all the images claim that `.complete` is true before I try to access their heights.

Comment: Are you using some other external JS library? Where is `.height()` defined?

Comment: Oh yeah... sorry it's jQuery. I'll edit the post

Comment: Try changing the jQuery `.height()` to native js `.naturalHeight` (check @[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)). Also, double check if you measure Image height **after** it was loaded.

Comment: If it does not work _sometimes_ perhaps you would want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588102/jquery-load-not-working-on-my-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working version of the resize function is as follows:

```
function resize( parent, images ) {
  // The largest height seen so far.
  var l = 0;

  // Loop through all the images to
  // determine which is the tallest.
  for ( var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i ) {

    // Create a variable to hold the current value.
    // This just means that we can save time on multiple
    // array access calls.
    var c = images[i];

    // If the current image is actually
    // visible to the user.
    if ( c.offsetParent !== null )

      // If the largest so far is the biggest then
      // keep it, otherwise change it to the new
      // biggest value.
      l = ( l > c.height ) ? l : c.height;
  }

  // If the value of 'l' is 0 then it is likely
  // that the all the images are hidden. In 
  // which case skip the resizing.
  if ( l === 0 )
     return;

  // Set the height of the parent to 'l'
  // this ensures that the parent will resize
  // even if the window is made smaller.
  // adding 2 pixels for good luck :P
  parent.setAttribute( "style", "height:" + (l + 2) + "px" );
}
```