# jQuery check image file exists

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [jQuery: Check if image exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327655/jquery-check-if-image-exists)
>   [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

I need to check if an image file exists and replace it with a default image in case the image does not exist on the server. Please let me know how can this be done using jQuery.

Comment: Check the answers of these questions: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327655/jquery-check-if-image-exists
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/check-if-image-exists-with-given-url-using-jquery You can just set error-handler for your image and replace image source to the default value.